# ShareActionProvider without menu or actionbar

Tags: android

In my project I need to share links of some photos from internet. Can I use ShareActionProvider without creating of options menu a actionbar.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No. `ShareActionProvider` requires an action bar.

However, you can call `startActivity()` on the `Intent` for sharing the links, and it will display a chooser activity if the user has not already set a default.

Comment: @raj: "Then what does this entail ?" -- then what does *what* entail? The rest of your comment has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: my bad wrong snippet - Note: While the sample snippet demonstrates how to use this provider in the context of a menu item, the use of the provider is not limited to menu items. on page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html

Comment: @raj: I have never seen an `ActionProvider` of any kind used outside the scope of a `MenuItem` representing an item for an action bar. Hence, I have no idea what that quoted passage (which, for future visitors to this answer, comes from [the `ShareActionProvider` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html)) could be referring to. And, since sharing of content does not require a `ShareActionProvider`, it is unclear what one would gain from trying to use it in anything other than an action bar.